# R - Conditionally sort multiple columns as ascending or descending by group

Tags: r, sorting

I haven't come across this problem before. I'd like to sort multiple columns as ascending or descending within a group depending on a condition

```
library(dplyr)
data <- mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl, disp)
```

If `cyl <= 4`, I'd like to sort `mpg, disp` (in that priority) in ascending order. If `cyl > 4`, I'd like to sort `mpg, disp` in descending order.

```
expected <- rbind(
    filter(data, cyl <= 4) %>% arrange(mpg, disp),
    filter(data, cyl > 4) %>% arrange(cyl, desc(mpg), desc(disp))
)
```

Comment: Your `expected` solution looks pretty reasonable. What are you hoping would be improved upon from that?

Comment: My real data has many groups and the condition is not always related to the grouping column - based on your comment, I realized I could always filter my data.frame based on multiple conditions and arrange accordingly. Still hoping for a "better" way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply each variable to be possibly reversed by `sign(4.1 - cyl)` :

```
mtcars %>% arrange(cyl, sign(4.1 - cyl) * mpg, sign(4.1 - cyl) * disp)
```

If `mpg`, say, were not numeric one could still do it by replacing `mpg` with `xtfrm(mpg)` which would map it to a numeric.  See `?xtfrm` .

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the values to negative to create new columns and then sort those columns.

```
library(dplyr)

data2 <- data %>%
  mutate_at(vars(mpg, cyl), funs(ifelse(cyl <= 4, ., -.))) %>%
  arrange(cyl, mpg2, disp2) %>%
  select(-ends_with("2"))
data2
#     mpg cyl  disp
# 1  21.4   4 121.0
# 2  21.5   4 120.1
# 3  22.8   4 108.0
# 4  22.8   4 140.8
# 5  24.4   4 146.7
# 6  26.0   4 120.3
# 7  27.3   4  79.0
# 8  30.4   4  75.7
# 9  30.4   4  95.1
# 10 32.4   4  78.7
# 11 33.9   4  71.1
# 12 21.4   6 258.0
# 13 21.0   6 160.0
# 14 21.0   6 160.0
# 15 19.7   6 145.0
# 16 19.2   6 167.6
# 17 18.1   6 225.0
# 18 17.8   6 167.6
# 19 19.2   8 400.0
# 20 18.7   8 360.0
# 21 17.3   8 275.8
# 22 16.4   8 275.8
# 23 15.8   8 351.0
# 24 15.5   8 318.0
# 25 15.2   8 304.0
# 26 15.2   8 275.8
# 27 15.0   8 301.0
# 28 14.7   8 440.0
# 29 14.3   8 360.0
# 30 13.3   8 350.0
# 31 10.4   8 472.0
# 32 10.4   8 460.0
```

Comment: Nice approach --