# Sort/arrange character column with condition

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I am trying to use `dplyr`'s `arrange` to sort character strings based on a condition. I'd like to `arrange` on a column, but in ascending order if a second column is equal to one value and in descending order if the second column is equal to another value.

I found a couple similar questions (one of them one of my own previous questions), but they weren't directly applicable. Both of them sorted on numeric columns and they wouldn't work on character columns.

[R - Conditionally sort multiple columns as ascending or descending by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917493/r-conditionally-sort-multiple-columns-as-ascending-or-descending-by-group)

[Sort/arrange within group for only chosen groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68765363/sort-arrange-within-group-for-only-chosen-groups)

Here's sample data:

```
df <- mtcars %>% as_tibble(rownames = "model") %>% select(model, mpg, cyl) %>% slice(1:8) %>% mutate(cond = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4)))
```

If cond == "A", I want to sort "model" in ascending order. If cond == "B", I want to sort "model" in descending order. I'd like a solution that doesn't rely on `bind_rows` or a similar solution.

Possibly something in the form of:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(ifelse(cond == "A", model, desc(model)))
```

The desired solution looks like:

```
## A tibble: 8 x 8
#  model              mpg   cyl cond 
#  <chr>              <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1 Datsun 710         22.8     4 A    
#2 Hornet 4 Drive     21.4     6 A    
#3 Mazda RX4          21       6 A    
#4 Mazda RX4 Wag      21       6 A    
#5 Valiant            18.1     6 B    
#6 Merc 240D          24.4     4 B    
#7 Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8 B    
#8 Duster 360         14.3     8 B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `dplyr::arrange` and `ifelse`. The trick is that {dplyr}'s `desc` function has a different output which is not the same type as its input:

```r
ifelse(df$cond == "B", dplyr::desc(df$model), df$model)
#> [1] "Mazda RX4"      "Mazda RX4 Wag"  "Datsun 710"     "Hornet 4 Drive"
#> [5] "-4"             "-8"             "-2"             "-7"
```

To make `desc()` inside an `ifelse` work the easist way is to define a function `asc()` which does just the opposite of `desc()`:

```r
asc <- function(x) {
  xtfrm(x)
}
```

Now we can use both `asc()` and `desc()` in the `ifelse` statement to return the desired ordering.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(cond, ifelse(cond == "B", desc(model), asc(model)))

#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   model               mpg   cyl cond 
#>   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 Datsun 710         22.8     4 A    
#> 2 Hornet 4 Drive     21.4     6 A    
#> 3 Mazda RX4          21       6 A    
#> 4 Mazda RX4 Wag      21       6 A    
#> 5 Valiant            18.1     6 B    
#> 6 Merc 240D          24.4     4 B    
#> 7 Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8 B    
#> 8 Duster 360         14.3     8 B
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

We may use `group_modify` and `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(cond) %>%
    group_modify(~.x %>% 
              arrange(if(.y == 'A') model else desc(model)) ) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(names(df))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  model               mpg   cyl cond 
  <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 Datsun 710         22.8     4 A    
2 Hornet 4 Drive     21.4     6 A    
3 Mazda RX4          21       6 A    
4 Mazda RX4 Wag      21       6 A    
5 Valiant            18.1     6 B    
6 Merc 240D          24.4     4 B    
7 Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8 B    
8 Duster 360         14.3     8 B
```

---

It is also possible to `subset` the values of 'model' `sort` it separately and specify those as `levels` in `factor` to be get `arrange`d accordingly

```
df %>%  
   arrange(factor(model, levels = c(sort(model[cond == 'A']), 
           sort(model[cond != "A"], decreasing = TRUE))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  model               mpg   cyl cond 
  <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 Datsun 710         22.8     4 A    
2 Hornet 4 Drive     21.4     6 A    
3 Mazda RX4          21       6 A    
4 Mazda RX4 Wag      21       6 A    
5 Valiant            18.1     6 B    
6 Merc 240D          24.4     4 B    
7 Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8 B    
8 Duster 360         14.3     8 B
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty messy, but it works.

```
mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "model") %>% 
  select(model, mpg, cyl) %>% 
  slice(1:8) %>% 
  mutate(cond = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4))) %>%
  group_by(cond) %>%
  arrange(model, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  add_rownames(., var = "rowna") %>%
  mutate(rowna = as.numeric(rowna)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(idx = ifelse(cond == "A", rowna, 8 - rowna)) %>%
  group_by(cond) %>%
  arrange(idx, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  select(-idx, -rowna)

  model               mpg   cyl cond 
  <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 Datsun 710         22.8     4 A    
2 Hornet 4 Drive     21.4     6 A    
3 Mazda RX4          21       6 A    
4 Mazda RX4 Wag      21       6 A    
5 Valiant            18.1     6 B    
6 Merc 240D          24.4     4 B    
7 Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8 B    
8 Duster 360         14.3     8 B
```

Answer (score 1):

As I find is often the case, a base R solution is much simpler:

```
split(df, df$cond) <- lapply(split(df, df$cond), function(d) {
    d[order(d$model, decreasing = all(d$cond == "B")),]
})
```

This splits the dataset by condition, then orders each split based on whether the condition is "A" or "B", and then re-inserts the splits into their respective places.